# Using series convergence to prove a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis

We are wanting to show that. Given a sequence $(a_n)$ such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ converges, show that $(a_n)$ converges.

My idea was to use the partial $m$-th sum of this series, then split it up into the $S_{2m}$ and $S_{2m+1}$ sums of $(a_n)$ and show that both of them converge. However, I am having trouble with this as we do not know if the sequences are monotonic or not. Would this be the right way to go about doing it?

Comment: Please visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset your question in MathJax. This will help draw interest and make it more readable. Someone has already edited most of your post; I might suggest learning the MathJax presented here for future questions.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sum|a_{k+1} - a_k|$ is convergent, the Cauchy criterion is satisfied by partial sums. For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $m > n > N$ we have

$$|a_m - a_n| \leqslant \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} |a_{k+1} - a_k| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} |a_{k+1} - a_k| - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |a_{k+1} - a_k| \right|< \epsilon$$

Therefore, $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and, hence, convergent.

Comment: I do not fully grasp where that initial inequality comes from. How do we know that this inequality holds?

Comment: The first one is a repeated application of the triangle inequality, eg. $|a_3 - a_2 + a_2 - a_1| \leqslant |a_3-a_2| + |a_2-a_1|$